# Are $P_{>3}$ in the vector space of all polynomials with coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the problem statement:

*The set of all polynomials of degree greater than 3 together with the zero polynomial in the vector space of $P$ of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.*

It is not subspace because the given description corresponds to an infinitely generated polynomial space?

Is that correct? If not, how I can solve this?

Comment: Vector spaces can be infinitely generated, as can their subspaces.  As the problem states, for example, the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ forms a vector space.  It is an infinitely-generated subspace of the set of polynomials in two variables.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a subspace because it's not stable by addition: take $F(X)=1-X^4, G(X)=X^4$. Then $F(X)+G(X)=1$ has degree $0$.

Comment: The ideal generated by $X^4$ doesn't contain any polynomials of degree $5$, though, does it?

Comment: It contains *all* polynomials of order  $\ge4$, plus $0$. For instance, $X^5=x\cdot X^4\in (x^4)$.

Comment: Right, sorry - I was thinking about the action of $\mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{R}[X]$. However, I still don't see how to get all polynomials of degree $4$, for example $X^4 + X$.

Comment: It's my turn to be sorry. I meant polynomials of *order* $\ge 4$ (the order in the sense of formal power series, for instance).

Comment: Ah, ok, and this is equivalent to being divisible by $X^4$. But this won't be the space described in the question, which is just about degree $\ge 4$.

Comment: Oh! Yes , I had read too hastily.. I'll change my answer in a moment.